# How to add new form field in moodle database module?

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

Moodle's Database module has some predefined field types (text, date, URL, picture, etc), but I want to customize this to create new field types.

For example, I might like to create a new field type name IMB and tells what can be done when the user select IMB in the form.

How to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The db field types live in `mod/data/field`.  You could copy one of the existing types and rename the folder to imb then rename the class to `data_field_imb` and start modifying away to get what you want.

There are only 2 files in their to worry about modifying (and an image if you want to get fancy). If you need to modify any onscreen text use the `get_string('stringkey', 'data')` or `print_string('stringkey', 'data')` then just make sure you put the stringkey and value into the file `lang/en_utf8/data.php`.

Good luck.

Comment: thanx a lot.. That helped a lot. Do u know do moodle receives data posted from the view/add form to the database, i wanna store them in some format different from how moodle e.g if i've several field and i want to store them in one field in the database separating them by certain character like "\n".. Thanx once again for your help!